# SONAR - Ant Script for sub Project

Tags: sonarqube

I have some projects and i wrote an ant script to run sonar with this projects.
Its okay so far. But i need to show these projects under a top level project like sub projects.

I am using just Ant to run sonar and i just working on pure code not on binaries.
(I just need to analysis)
I could not find how i can solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have 2 choices:

- Either those projects are really linked together, and you can configure an Ant build script to have a multi-module project that wraps all your projects => http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Analyse+with+Ant+Task#AnalysewithAntTask-Analysemultimodulesproject
- Or those projects are different (=> they have different lifecycles, they are functionnaly different, ...), and the best option is to use the Views Plugin => http://www.sonarsource.com/plugins/plugin-views/Overview/

Comment: I know this is a little bit late, but can you please explain the benefit of using a multi module project as oppose to just including all of the source and binaries of the projects in the parent build.xml ?

Comment: This will make it easier for you to monitor a specific module of your project in Sonar: you will have aggregated metrics per module, whereas everything would be mixed if you include all the sources in the parent build.xml

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need the Views-Plugin: http://www.sonarsource.com/plugins/plugin-views/Overview/

> The SonarSource Views Product enables the creation of any aggregation
>   trees to regroup projects. Projects can for instance be grouped by
>   applications, applications by team, teams by department… Each level of
>   the tree is a View and offers all standard services such as dashboard,
>   hotspots, timemachine, drilldown… showing the consolidated measures.

Comment: Views plug-in is well worth paying for

Comment: @İsaGöl Just a friendly reminder (not fishign for reputation ;) ): you can [accept answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/160062) that really helped you. It is Stackoverflows way of saying thanks.